# PriorityQueue \ java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, priority-queue

Can't think about a better way printing toString with PQ, natural ordered, than copying the entire collection to another one, and using poll method.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. It is hard to see what you are asking.

Comment: i'm trying to create a multimap, holding (for an example) a key that represents the number of chars, and value holding a collection of strings, with the specific number of chars. both of the collections are natural ordered (integers, a-b). there is no much need using remove \ put methods- that's why i was thinking about using PQ, and not TreeSet SortedArrayList etc..

Comment: example: input-
bbbbb
jjjjj
kkk
aaa
nnn 
     output- [map={3=[aaa, kkk, nnn], 5=[bbbbb, jjjjj]}]

Comment: PriorityQueue is the *wrong* object to use as the basis of a multi-map. Its contract has  very little in common with the contract required by a map.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the order the PriorityQUeue would be if it were fully sorted, you need to copy it to a Sorted collection like TreeSet

e.g.

```
System.out.println(new TreeSet(pq)); // prints elements naturally sorted.
```

Note: this will discard duplicates, a PriorityQueue does not.

---

Even though sorting is O(n * log n) and printing is O(n) This is not the whole story.  Sorting in memory is much faster than using any IO meaning that you need an insanely large queue for the sorting to be more significant.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    PriorityQueue<Double> pq = new PriorityQueue<Double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10*1000 * 1000; i++)
        pq.add(Math.random());
    long start1 = System.nanoTime();
    Set<Double> set = new TreeSet<Double>(pq);
    long time1 = System.nanoTime() - start1;

    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    for (Double d : set) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
    long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
    System.out.printf("It took %.3f seconds to sort, and %.3f seconds to print %,d doubles%n", time1 / 1e9, time2 / 1e9, pq.size());
}
```

prints at the end

```
It took 28.359 seconds to sort, and 94.844 seconds to print 10,000,000 doubles
```

If I use an array and sort that it is

```
Double[] doubles = pq.toArray(new Double[pq.size()]);
Arrays.sort(doubles);

It took 8.377 seconds to sort ....
```

In short, you are likely to run out of memory or exceed the maximum length of a String  before you have a queue long enough for sorting to be the most significant.

Comment: it is a problem because i have a PQ for each key in the list. it is not efficient enough

Comment: The sorting will be trivial compared with the cost of generating the toString which will be trivial compared with the cost of the IO if you write it somewhere. Can you clarify what you are doing and what do you mean by "fast enough"?

Comment: the complexity doing that with treeSet is o(nlogn), since the usage of remove and put methods is not great, i'm trying to find a better way implementing this

Comment: even if it is trivial small compared to anything else you are going? Your queue needs to be insanely long for it to be the problem.

Comment: lets say that i have to use only PQ for implementing this, and i can not use any other collection. is there any way doing that?

Comment: You can, but only destructively. i.e the queue will be empty when you finish. You can pass all the elements you see to another queue and replace the original.

Comment: As a String is limited to 2 billion characters so you can only toString a collection of up to 200 million (assuming about 10 characters per element including separators) At 200m entries, the toString and IO will still take longer than the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Override `toString()` method in the Object which you are adding in Any collection then`toString` Method works fine

```
    PriorityQueue<String> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<String>();
    priorityQueue.add("one");
    priorityQueue.add("two");
    priorityQueue.add("three");
    System.out.println(priorityQueue);//Prints [one, two, three]
```